# Get records for this week

Tags: php, mysqli

I need to pull a list of records with a SCHDT for this week. The problem is the dates are entered as 30116 for March 1, 2016 and 101016 as October 10, 2016

I need to show all records for this week, then be able to go back a week or forward a week.

```
select SCHDT from patinfo WHERE SCHDT = 'this week'
```

Comment: i wouldent bother until i fixed the date storage. Short term pain for long term gain

Comment: Do as @Dagon says. Add a column in `DATETIME` or `DATE` format, and convert your data. That would make this problem very easy to solve using `DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)` or `DATE_ADD( NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have option to use PHP, try to fetch the current week dates in the same format as saved in the database and query with that dates.

```
$week_stard_date = date("ndy",strtotime('monday this week')); //22916
$week_end_date = date("ndy",strtotime('sunday this week')); //30616

select SCHDT from patinfo WHERE SCHDT BETWEEN $week_stard_date AND $week_end_date
```